# Call a pandas dataframe using its name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reference

I have read different csv files as different dataframes as shown below

```
df1=pd.read_csv('test.csv)
df2=pd.read_csv('test1.csv)
df3=pd.read_csv('test2.csv)
df4=pd.read_csv('test3.csv)
df5=pd.read_csv('test4.csv)`
```

Now I wanted to create combinations of from the above mentioned dataframes like follows

```
for i in range (0,6):
   for j in range (i+1,6):
       di='df'+str(i)
       dj='df'+str(j)
       print(di,dj)
       print(di.iloc(:,4),dj.iloc(:,4))`
```

When I print di and dj it prints as follows
df1 df2
df1 df3
df1 df4
df1 df5
df1 df6
df1 df7
df1 df8
df1 df9
df2 df3
df2 df4
df2 df5

and so on............

But the 4th column of the dataframe is not printed. Instead an error is thrown as 'string doe snot have an attribute .iloc' So what I anticipate is instead of dfi being a variable used for referring a dataframe, it has created it as a string.

Any inputs and suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Use a dictionary: `{'df1':pd.read_csv('test.csv),...}`. Then you can construct key names in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Defining several `dfN` variables was an unfortunate design choice.
Let's arrange them in a more convenient `list`.

```
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f"test{i}.csv") for i in range(5)]
```

Now you can write

```
for i in range(0, len(dfs)):
   for j in range(i + 1, len(dfs)):
       di = dfs[i]
       dj = dfs[j]
       print(i, j, di, dj)
       print(di.iloc(:, 4), dj.iloc(:, 4))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs. But unfortunately I had to do so because of the way the files are stored. All the files are not stored in the same location and all files do not have the names with similar patterns as well. the code given here is just an example. I will work on to see if I can make a list of dataframes as you had mentioned.

Comment: Aahhhh, so it's an [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) problem, is it? Write a helper which `yield`s relevant filenames, perhaps using [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk).